# Fabric.js - use percentages for image/object sizes

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to add an image to my canvas element using fabricjs and i need to be able to set/adjust the sizes by percentages not set pixels.

http://jsfiddle.net/F2P9Y/1/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://s17.postimg.org/4740ku7z3/i_Stock_000000284123_XSmall.jpg',     function (oImg) {
    oImg.setWidth(480);
    oImg.setHeight(360);
    canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

Is there anyway i can have a percentage inside the `setWidth()` and `setHeight()`? I am wanting to set it at a percentage of the canvas container, so i want the image width to always be 60% of the canvas (the canvas is dynamic and can be different amounts) so in this instance 480 for the canvas width of 800 but if the canvas was to be 600 equals 360 width

I get an unexpected token when i try to insert `setWidth('60%')`

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the value calculated from the canvas size:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var percentage = 0.6;

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://s17.postimg.org/4740ku7z3/i_Stock_000000284123_XSmall.jpg', function (oImg) {
    oImg.scaleToWidth(canvas.width*percentage);
    console.log("Image width: ", oImg.currentWidth);
    canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

Here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F2P9Y/4/
regards, Benick